# scrlttr2 documentclass options

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I'm "getting angry" with the documentation of scrlttr2 class.
I would see all the option I can include in that class. I have the manual of koma-script, but I can't find that doc.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't follow: you say yo have the KOMA-Script manual but then say you can't find it. At the Terminal/Command Prompt `texdoc scrguien` should open the PDF.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user7143".

Comment: ok, I've done it. It create the same manual that I already have,but here, I can't find the info that I need. Can you tell me where I can look for?

Comment: searching for "option" leads to a table of contents entry for "index of Class and Package Options" and clicking on that takes you to said index on page 416

Comment: This question is very unspecific and unclear. Please try to improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both versions of the KOMA-Script manual (the printed version [includes more informations] and the pdf version [`texdoc scrguien` or german `texdoc scrguide`]) you will find in the index the Class Options and the Package options.  The page numbers differs if you use the german or english, the printed or pdf version.

The KOMA-Script manual describes all options you can use, but you have to look into the index and search that one you need.

Or you can add what you need to your question.

In the German version you will find on page 453 (Chapter 21, class and package options):

[image: Options for KOMA-Script]

All of this options and there values can be used for class `scr...` or KOMA-Script packages. The meaning and result is described on the page(s) you can click on in the index. The red numbers are links to the page ...

Comment: This is the line of my index: 
\documentclass .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 28–29
at that page, I cannot find any options described...

Comment: @RenatoP Sorry I missed your comment. I do not understand. What has `\documentclass...28-29` to do with your problem? I added an image to my answer (in German language). If that does not help please explain more what your problem is ...